# Error with Python: TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, dataframe, logistic-regression

Every time I run the code below, I get an error that says that fit is missing 1 required positional argument (y), but my "y" value is specified in my code.

```
X_var = myData['PredictorName']
y = myData['TaskOutcome']
LogisticRegression()
LogisticRegression.fit(X_var, y)
```

I've tried a number of different ways of pulling the data outside of the df, but none seem to be working.

This is my output for y.head() (which is and should be a series of 1's and 0's)

```
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
Name: Task, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You forgot to call the constructor: `LogisticRegression.fit(X_var, y)` must be `LogisticRegression().fit(X_var, y)`.

Comment: better yet, if you want to use this model for any predictions, store your previous call (`LogisticRegression()`) into a variable (e.g. `model = LogisticRegression()`), then fit as `model.fit()`.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your call to the constructor to a variable and then call the fit function on this variable.

```
X_var = myData['PredictorName']
y = myData['TaskOutcome']
logistic_regression = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_var, y)
```